# Speech recognition in vb6

Tags: vb6, speech-recognition

Anyone know how to code speech recognition that Microsoft speech recognition will detect set word.... any references i have put all the code which can make recognition but do know how to code Microsoft speech recognition will detect set word....

My coding:

```
Option Explicit
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim recognizer As SpInprocRecognizer
Dim MyGrammer As ISpeechRecoGrammar
Dim grammar As ISpeechRecoGrammar
Dim InputFile As SpeechLib.SpFileStream
Private Sub Form_Load()

Set RC = New SpInProcRecoContext
Set recognizer = RC.recognizer
Set myGrammar = RC.CreateGrammar
myGrammar.DictationSetState SGDSActive

Dim Category As SpObjectTokenCategory
Set Category = New SpObjectTokenCategory
Category.SetId SpeechCategoryAudioIn

Dim Token As SpObjectToken
Set Token = New SpObjectToken
Token.SetId Category.Default()
Set recognizer.AudioInput = Token

Out 888, 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Before, SSR M.S. and releated company make TTS - Text-To-Speech, basic engine for TTS is foenemmology - phonemes for speak P.C. to louds and phonemes for speech recognition over mcirophone. How like P.C. speak words it except of human to say words to microphone, but a lot of words have same speak and different write in the sentence. In the other hand, SSR engine except tempo, pronuanciation-(For example: Clear-north-american-low-accented speak english language (not loud, just clear speak) ), middle-average of power of your speak words in the microphone against of out of louds and some time for training SSR engine for collect information about that in own data-system. SSR use work of TTS and of own engine for specific language to produce speech recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is on this web page
http://www.martin2k.co.uk/vb6/tips/vb_10.php

Comment: Link you provided is 404

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, there are two types of speech recognition, dictation and command and control. In dictation mode, you are listening for every word possible and trying to find a match. This is good for dictation type systems where a person is speaking and you wish to transcribe everything. A good example of dictation grammar is converting a voicemail to text. Command and control uses a limited grammar which increases accuracy. If by "set word" you mean a set number of words, then command and control is what you want. An example would be an IVR system where you play a prompt and wait for a response, "Please press 1 for sales and 2 for support". The grammar would only contain "1 or 2". The word one might sound like a lot of different words if we were searching through the entire language dictionary, but comparing the difference between only the words 1 and 2 is easy. Here is one sample to help anyone learning about speech recognition:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720589(v=vs.85).aspx

You can see how to load a grammar from a file and how to structure an XML file that holds your grammar.